# Posterior mode, posterior mean and posterior variance of a posterior distribution of dirichlet form

Tags: variance, mean, posterior, dirichlet-distribution, mode

What is the significance of finding the posterior  mean, posterior mode and posterior variance in Dirichlet - multinomial conjugate pair Bayesian estimation?   Are all of them equally important while estimating a posterior probability? Which should be chosen out of the three?

Comment: In general, it all depends on the loss function. For example posterior mean is the estimator when a quadraric loss function is used and the posterior mode when a 0-1 loss function is used. Also one can take the absolute error loss which leads to the posterior median. Is this helpful?

Comment: I am basically not from a statistical ground. What is meant by a loss function? In bayesian analysis using a dirichlet-multinomial conjugate pairs at which point I can find the type of loss function? Hope this doubt is not a blunder. I know only the basic concepts of Bayesian logic.

Comment: You cannot determine the loss function from the posterior distribution. I will try to give an explanation in my answer below beacuse it does not fit in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain this in general not focusing on the Dirichlet-Multinomial case and based on some Decision theory notions. The Bayes estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is the rule that minimizes the expected posterior loss 
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\theta|x}[L(\theta,\hat{\theta})]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}L(\theta,\hat{\theta}) \pi(\theta|x)d\theta
$$

where $\pi(\theta|x)$ is the posterior distribution and $L(\theta,\hat{\theta})$ is the loss function. The loss function measures how much we "pay" when we choose an "action" $\hat{\theta}$ and the true value is $\theta.$ For example the quadratic loss function is given by
$$
L(\theta,\hat{\theta}) = (\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2.
$$ 
So if you choose as a point estimator the posterior mean $\hat{\theta}=\mathbb{E}_{\theta|x}\theta$ this minimizes the expected posterior loss when the quadratic loss function is used.

The median of the posterior distribution minimizes the expected posterior loss when 
$$
L(\theta,\hat{\theta})=c|\hat{\theta}-\theta|, \quad c>0,
$$
the absolute loss function.

The choice of the estimator depends on the application. For example if one has a multimodal posterior distribution it is not reasonable to assume that the posterior mean is an appropriate estimate and should take the posterior mode. That is the assumption is that the $0-1$ loss function has been used
$$
L(\theta,\hat{\theta}) = \begin{cases} 0,\quad |\hat{\theta}-\theta|<0\\
1,\quad |\hat{\theta}-\theta|\geq 0\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: From your answer I conclude that the Bayes estimators :  posterior mean, posterior mode and posterior median minimizes the expected posterior loss when, the quadratic loss function , 0-1 loss function and absolute loss function is used respectively . But how can I know which Bayes estimator minimizes the expected posterior loss in my posterior distribution and which type of loss function I have to use/ assume in my work.

Comment: You have given in your  answer that "The choice of the estimator depends on the application. For example if one has a multimodal posterior distribution it is not reasonable to assume that the posterior mean is an appropriate estimate and should take the posterior mode". My 'posterior distribution' is a 'dirichlet' form as I used 'dirichlet-multinomial conjugate pairs' in the bayesian analysis. Is it a 'multi modal posterior distribution'? Can I use 'posterior mode ' as my Bayes estimator?

Comment: Well, you find the posterior distribution, this has nothing to do yet with the loss function. Then you take for example the posterior mean. This means you have chosen to minimize the quadratic loss function.

Comment: About the choice of the estimator in the Dirichlet-Multinomial case you can take the posterior mean for each component of the vector of probabilities.

Comment: I hope i helped. Let me know if there is something else.

Comment: @anagharaveendran your loss function has to with the consequences of making a mistake.  For example, a surgeon unable to locate an artery is facing a radically different type of loss than a gambler playing cards.  Let's imagine hitting the artery is fatal.  Then there is no cost if it is missed and infinite if hit.  That is essentially 0-1 loss.  For a gambler, quadratic loss is appropriate due to the linkage with revenue and the demand curve.  What happens in the event you get a bad sample?